# alternative tables all_types for package define types in oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle19c

I use oracle 19. The following type is declared in the package.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE package MYUSER.mytest is
      TYPE MY_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);

      FUNCTION mytable_test ( in_param IN MY_TABLE , out_param OUT MY_TABLE , inout_param IN OUT MY_TABLE )
               RETURN MY_TABLE ;
end mytest;
```

I need to understand this type of object or collection.  I usually do this with the following query:

```
SELECT  * FROM all_types WHERE OWNER = 'MYUSER', TYPE_NAME  = 'MY_TABLE';
```

But it doesn't work for types declared inside the package. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `all_plsql_types` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM all_plsql_types
WHERE OWNER = 'MYUSER'
AND TYPE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

As you know it's a collection type you can dig in a bit further with `all_plsql_coll_types`:

```
SELECT * FROM all_plsql_coll_types
WHERE OWNER = 'MYUSER'
AND TYPE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b794e14b80afab75810c2f9dca7d998)

Documentation for [`all_plsql_types`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_PLSQL_TYPES.html) and [`all_plsql_coll_types`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_PLSQL_COLL_TYPES.html).